# How to get the correct object format when doing ExecuteScalar on a database?

Tags: c#, database

I have a database table with different column types, like for example:

```
Column 1   Column 2   Column 3   Column 4 
(string)   (decimal)  (string)   (int)
```

I have create a class that has the exact same format, lets call it `DbTableFormat` for this example. I am doing a select in C# using the `ExecuteScalar` method of the `ISqlDataBase` like this:

```
List<DbTableFormat> myTable = db.ExecuteScalar<List<DbTableFormat>>("SELECT * FROM dbTableName 
WHERE whatever")
```

- `db` is a `ISqlDataBase`

I would expect to be able to get a list in the correct format, but instead I get the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DbTableFormat]'.

Why is it considering it as a int32 and what am I not understanding in this conversion? Because I obviously don't understand it completely.

Comment: Where does the `ISqlDataBase` interface come from?  `ExecuteScalar` likely returns the value from the first row/column of the result set.  Are there other methods that would be more appropriate?

Comment: I suppose there must be, as ExecuteScalar definitely doesn't do what I need.

Comment: So what other methods are there on that interface?  Is there any documentation to indicate how it works?  What library is that interface from?

Comment: Oh right, I thought ISqlDataBase was a standard class. Let me try to find details.